# security issues using azure remoteapp

Tags: security, azure, remoteapp

To who it may concern,

I am looking to move more of our applications that the company uses to azure. I have found that Remote App will allow people to us the apps I have allowed via the Remote App. The application which will be used is linked to a database which is on site, I am just worried about people being able to access this database as it will contain important data which cant be leaked. I am trying to work out what are some security precautions which could be taken to prevent the data from being viewed by the wrong people. I have seen app locker to stop applications on the virtual machine from being accessed. Any other security suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine. Remote app is running remotely - meaning that theres no way of getting to the connection string (reverse engineering). Access to the app is also ensured by AAD login. The database should be protected as well with AD credentials. Also, adding a service tier that fronts the database would provide a facade.